# Finding magnitude of forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, vectors

3 forces From there i have to find the magnitude?

This is my first time taking physics and I would really appreciate any help.
I know that F= m*a , but i need the mass and in this case i don't have the mass.
I wonder if i could use the coefficient for gravity which is 9.81 m/s^2 as my mass?

Comment: Hi Dee and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the object is at rest, you don't need to know the mass. We know that the only way an object will stay at rest if there is no *net* force - that is, the sum of all the forces (as vectors) must be zero.

So I recommend you try drawing a vector diagram. Draw arrows in the specified directions - one with a known length, and two with unknown length (but known direction).

Now you know that the sum of all horizontal and vertical forces on the object must be zero. One way to get the sum of two vectors is to lay them "head to tail". You can do the same thing with the three vectors in this case - and when you put them head to tail, and their sum is zero, they must end up in the same place where you started, making a triangle.

See if you can take it from here.

Comment: Okay and once i have the "triangle" can i use trigonometry to find the missing sides and that will give me the magnitude of the forces? Bu thanks for the information I appreciate it so much ! @Floris

Comment: That's exactly how you do it yes. Note that since this is a homework-like problem, we don't give complete solutions - just pointers to the principles at work. But it sounds like you are able to figure it out from here.